# Jira API addBase64EncodedAttachmentsToIssue not working for status = closed

Tags: migration, jira

I am currently migrating issues from Salesforce to Jira. As attachments could not be imported properly, I imported other fields to Jira and wrote Java code to get attachment files from Salesforce to add them to the corresponding issues in Jira.

Other than closed issues I am able to add attachments with the the API `addBase64EncodedAttachmentsToIssue`. But for the closed status in Jira I am not able to add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change **jira.issue.editable** property of the workflow to **true** while you are performing migration. This will make the issue editable and you will be able to add attachments. In default Jira workflow all closed issues are uneditable by default.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow#uneditable_steps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. We are asked to use default Jira workflow. I tried to configure the property. But it is saying Read only. I could not make changes to. Is it advisable to use workflow which is other than default.

Comment: To edit an active workflow you must create a draft for it. Here is how - http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow#ConfiguringWorkflow-Editinganactiveworkflow